# Refresh of paint in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have got this code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
z = plt.scatter([3,5], [1.11212,1.11215])

axcolor = '#ffffff'
ax_x_pos = plt.axes([0.086, 0.198, 0.828, 0.022], axisbg=axcolor)
x_pos = Slider(ax_x_pos, '', 0, 100, valfmt='%d',
           valinit=100, color='green')

x_pos.valtext.set_visible(False)

def updateX(val):
    global z
    z.remove()
    plt.scatter([3,5], [1.11212,1.11215])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

cid = x_pos.on_changed(updateX)
plt.show()
```

How will i can draw anything after remove "Z" param?
(I got taken empty canvas(after "on_changed()") it all.)

I mean.
I need just draw some paint and then replace it with another paint.

P.S. I will be appreciate for any advice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define an axis, `ax` so plots should be drawn on that (`ax.scatter` instead of `plt.scatter`). Also, in update you don't use the slider value `val` to change the values you plot.

An example which changes the plot and redraws is as follows,

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
z = ax.scatter([3,5], [1.11212,1.11215])

axcolor = '#ffffff'
ax_x_pos = plt.axes([0.086, 0.1, 0.828, 0.022], axisbg=axcolor)
x_pos = Slider(ax_x_pos, '', 0, 100, valfmt='%d',
           valinit=100, color='green')

x_pos.valtext.set_visible(False)

def updateX(val):
    global z
    z.remove()
    z = ax.scatter([3*val/100.,5], [1.11212,1.11215*val/100.])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

cid = x_pos.on_changed(updateX)
plt.show()
```